# Integrating Spring Boot and Reactor-Kafka's KafkaReceiver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-kafka

I am trying to develop a Spring Boot application using the library `reactor-kafka` to react to some messages read from a Kafka topic.

I have a configuration class that builds a `KafkaReceiver`.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        // Options initialisation...
        final ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions =
                ReceiverOptions.<String, string>create(props)
                               .subscription(Collections.singleton(consumer.getTopic()));
        return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions);
    } 
}
```

Well...and now? Using not-so-reactive `spring-kafka` library, I can annotate a method with `@KafkaListener` and Spring Boot will create for me a thread listening from a Kafka topic.

Where should I place the `KafkaReceiver`, instead? In all the examples I found the use directly the `main` method, but this is not the *Boot way*.

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.3 and Reactor-Kafka 1.1.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have that `KafkaReceiver` bean, now you can do like this:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver) {
        return args -> {
                kafkaReceiver.receive()
                          ...
                          .sunbscribe();
        };
}
```

This `ApplicationRunner` bean is going to be kicked when the `ApplicationContext` is ready. See its JavaDocs for more info.

Comment: Many thanks. Maybe, you can add this integration somewhere in the documentation :)

Comment: how do you run multiple consumers of the same consumer group?

Comment: Would you mind to raise a new SO thread with more details? Doesn’t look like related to this old one...